# Sorting array into three different ArrayLinearLists

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

[You can find ArrayLinearLists from here in EPROGS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eprog/) Trying to sort a datas from .txt file into three different ArrayLinearLists. But the problem is about their capacity. Whenever the .add function is called the capacity is doubled. [image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line;
    int indexOfCode = 0;
    int indexOfName = 1;
    int indexOfCredit = 2;
    int count = 0;
    ArrayLinearList codeR = new ArrayLinearList();
    ArrayLinearList nameR = new ArrayLinearList();
    ArrayLinearList creditR = new ArrayLinearList();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Subjects.txt"))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String values[] = line.split("/");
            codeR.add(0, values[indexOfCode]);
            nameR.add(0, values[indexOfName]);
            creditR.add(0, values[indexOfCredit]);
        }

        System.out.println(codeR);
        System.out.println(nameR);
        System.out.println(creditR);

    }
}
```

}
Here is the ArrayLinearList codes

```
protected Object[] element; // array of elements
protected static int size; // number of elements in array
protected static ArrayLinearList theObject;

// constructors
/**
 * create a list with initial capacity initialCapacity
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             when initialCapacity < 1
 */
public ArrayLinearList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialCapacity must be >= 1");
    // size has the default initial value of 0
    element = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

/** create a list with initial capacity 10 */
public ArrayLinearList() {// use default capacity of 10
    this(10);
}

// methods
/** @return true iff list is empty */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

/** @return current number of elements in list */
public int size() {
    return size;
}

/**
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *             when index is not between 0 and size - 1
 */
void checkIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index = " + index + "  size = " + size);
}

/**
 * @return element with specified index
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *             when index is not between 0 and size - 1
 */
public Object get(int index) {
    checkIndex(index);
    return element[index];
}

/**
 * @return index of first occurrence of theElement, return -1 if theElement
 *         not in list
 */
public int indexOf(Object theElement) {
    // search element[] for theElement
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (element[i].equals(theElement))
            return i;

    // theElement not found
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Remove the element with specified index. All elements with higher index
 * have their index reduced by 1.
 * 
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *             when index is not between 0 and size - 1
 * @return removed element
 */
public Object remove(int index) {
    checkIndex(index);

    // valid index, shift elements with higher index
    Object removedElement = element[index];
    for (int i = index + 1; i < size; i++)
        element[i - 1] = element[i];

    element[--size] = null; // enable garbage collection
    return removedElement;
}

/**
 * Insert an element with specified index. All elements with equal or higher
 * index have their index increased by 1.
 * 
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *             when index is not between 0 and size
 */
public void add(int index, Object theElement) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size)
        // invalid list position
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index = " + index + "  size = " + size);

    // valid index, make sure we have space
    if (size == element.length)
        // no space, double capacity
        element = ChangeArrayLength.changeLength1D(element,2* size);

    // shift elements right one position
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= index; i--)
        element[i + 1] = element[i];

    element[index] = theElement;

    size++;
}

/** convert to a string */
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("[");

    // put elements into the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (element[i] == null)
            s.append("null, ");
        else
            s.append(element[i].toString() + ", ");

    if (size > 0)
        s.delete(s.length() - 2, s.length()); // remove last ", "

    s.append("]");

    // create equivalent String
    return new String(s);
}

/** create and return an iterator */
public Iterator iterator() {
    return new ArrayLinearListIterator((MyArrayList) this);
}

/** test program */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test default constructor
    LinearList x = new ArrayLinearList();

    // test size
    System.out.println("Initial size is " + x.size());

    // test isEmpty
    if (x.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    else
        System.out.println("The list is not empty");

    // test put
    x.add(0, new Integer(2));
    x.add(1, new Integer(6));
    x.add(0, new Integer(1));
    x.add(2, new Integer(4));
    System.out.println("List size is " + x.size());

    // test toString
    System.out.println("The list is " + x);

    // test indexOf
    int index = x.indexOf(new Integer(4));
    if (index < 0)
        System.out.println("4 not found");
    else
        System.out.println("The index of 4 is " + index);

    index = x.indexOf(new Integer(3));
    if (index < 0)
        System.out.println("3 not found");
    else
        System.out.println("The index of 3 is " + index);

    // test get
    System.out.println("Element at 0 is " + x.get(0));
    System.out.println("Element at 3 is " + x.get(3));

    // test remove
    System.out.println(x.remove(1) + " removed");
    System.out.println("The list is " + x);
    System.out.println(x.remove(2) + " removed");
    System.out.println("The list is " + x);

    if (x.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    else
        System.out.println("The list is not empty");

    System.out.println("List size is " + x.size());

}
```

}
And thanks in advance ,great senior developers :D

Comment: What is `ArrayLinearList`? It is not from the standard library.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz see the third tab in the image. So it might be a custom class. @ OP: we need some insight in that code as well.

Comment: @Meld also add `ArrayLinearList.java` code snippet.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. 1. The capacity shouldn't really concern you, 2. It doesn't look like the capacity doubles with every `add`. What makes you think it does?

Answer (score 0):

For a *developer using ArrayLinearList* this means giving a larger initial capacity, to prevent too many increases.

Using an estimate:

```
Path path = Paths.get("Subjects.txt");
int initialCapacity = (int)(Files.size(path) / 3);
```

For a *developer implementing ArrayLinearList* heshe could pick a larger default initial capacity, or something like increasing the array size by `1000 + array.length/4`, to not waiste as much space, and initially have not so many repeated increases.